# onActivityResult cause activity to reset/restart

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have an activity FirstActivity with two textviews. To fill each textview, I call another activity for result with `startActivityForResult`. My problem is, when onActivityResult is called, whichever textView was previously set gets cleared. Is there a lifecycle call that would prevent this from occurring?

Comment: Please show us some code!

Comment: Have you tried saving and restoring the instanceState of your FirstActivity ? Try looking here at : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: @Android2390 according to the link (i.e. official docs): `The default implementation of this method saves information about the state of the activity's view hierarchy, such as the text in an EditText widget or the scroll position of a ListView.` But that is exactly what is getting cleared.

Comment: @Android2390 actually that helped. I managed to make it work by saving the actual data and repopulating the views. Do you mind reposting so I may mark this thread as answered?

Comment: Sure. Glad you could get it to work :)